# Error: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier while using IERC20

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, interfaces

Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "@opengsn/gsn/contracts/BaseRelayRecipient.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";


contract MyContract is BaseRelayRecipient{
    constructor(address _trustedForwarder) public {
        trustedForwarder = _trustedForwarder;
    }
    
    
    function transfertip(address to_, uint256 amount_) public {
        address contract_ = 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB;
    
      ERC20Interface =  IERC20(contract_);
      ERC20Interface.transfer(to_, amount_);
    
    
    }
    
   
    function versionRecipient() external view override returns (string memory) {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

Error:

> DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. ERC20Interface = IERC20(contract_);
>
> DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. ERC20Interface.transfer(to_, amount_);

Comment: Hey Ramit, welcome to StackExchane. You need to add more information if you want someone on this forum to help you. What framework are you using (Hardhat, Truffle, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ERC20Interface =  IERC20(contract_);`  the problem comes from here, the correct syntax is `IERC20 ERC20Interface =  IERC20(contract_);`